# Is there a way to record names without a database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing a chatbot on Dialogflow. My problem is my bot doesn't remember names.

My intention is not to save datas from the users, but give my bot ability to remember them in the long term every time they ask.

I have already tried: 
given-name
given-name

Oh, welcome #given-name.given name.

To be more clean,
It is the same idea with the bot "mitsuku". When I ask her my name, every time she says: Of course I remember, your name is xxx.

My problem is I can do the same thing with my bot, but after a while, the bot doesn't remember the users.

Is there a way to handle this problem without Webhook? Because I am not familiar with Firebase or Node.js.

Comment: Any way to save data and make them accessible via some form of search or query at a later time is some kind of database; the question just is what kind, whether self-implemented or resorting to existing solutions. Given your description and total lack of details on your implementation, this question probably cannot be answered sensibly and must be considered too broad or missing focus

Comment: What do you specifically mean with "On the long term"? Is this within the same conversation or do you want to remember data when the user talks to your bot during a different conversation?

Comment: Yes, that's right. For example, the bot " Mitsuku" remembers my name all the time when I ask.

Comment: If you want your bot to remember it all the time, then I am afraid it isn't possible without a database or other way of storage as Beppe has already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think thats possible, you want to persist some (user) data so you will need a database or a file, and the integration happens with a [webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview).

You dont need to use Firebase or Node, Dialogflow allows to configure an HTTP URL which will point to your webhook: you can choose from a variety of languages and examples.

Comment: Can you say if it is possible to trigger firebase cloud function when a discord bot message is detected? possible using webhook you talking about ?

Comment: The webhook (fulfillment) if enabled is invoked when the platform recognises an Intent: at the point you can apply the logic you need (ie is a discord bot then do this, if not do that)

Comment: Okay, my intention to ask this was can we generate a HTTPS request on a message sent to discord bot like telegram bot does. This way we could easily use firebase for discord bots. Still researching on it.